# telegram MessageEntity phone_number

Tags: php, curl, telegram, guzzle

I'm  using GuzzleHttp\Client to send message. how to make a phone number clickable?

```
    $apiURL = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $apiKey . '/';
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => $apiURL]);
    $message = $event->getTitle() . ' ' . $event->contact;
    $response = $client->post('sendMessage',
         [
            'multipart' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'chat_id',
                    'contents' => $chatID
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'text',
                    'contents' => '8-999-123-45-67',

                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'entities',
                    'contents' => json_encode([['type' => 'phone_number', 'length' => 15, 'offset' => 0]]),
                ],
            ]
    ]);
```

It doesn't work. But work other entities: text_link and  pre.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, not all entities are available in "sendMessage". I solved it via "sendContact" method

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33111968)